# Enter Value in one HTML page and other html page shows it dynamically, without a new one everytime

Tags: javascript, html

Requirements

1. Add value to a field in one html page.
2. Submit.
3. Should show the value on another html page.
4. Any update on first page should update the second page and not open a new one.

I have written some HTML which is below. What is happening is that once I press submit it opens another page (page2.html) in same window. What I want is to have two html windows and whenever I update Home page it should reflect on the same page. (page2.html)

```
Home.html
<code>

<html>
    <form target="_blank" type=get action="page2.html">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>OrderID:</td>
                <td><input type=text name=orderId size=10></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</html>
```

```
page2.html

<code>

<html>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function getParams(){
            var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
            var params = new Array();
            if (idx != -1) {
                 var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
                for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
                    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
                }
             }

             return params;
        }
        params = getParams();
        firstname = unescape(params["orderId"]);
        document.write("OrderID = " + firstname + "<br>");
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize params to an empty object instead of an array:

```
var params = {};
```

That will allow you to use strings and other values for a key.

Be sure you include var when declaring variables:

```
var params = getParams();

var firstName = unescape(params["orderId"]);
```

It's fine for learning, but try to never use document.write. It's better to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild. In this case, you can add it to the body by doing:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "OrderID = " + firstname;
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Other then that, your code looks fine. Please comment if you're still having issues. Use firebug or chrome's console to post any errors.

Comment: I want that when i say submit on the home.html it open a new html page first time (page2.html) and thereafter when ever i update the first page and say submit it should reflect on page2.html (same one which is open and not a new one)

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by adding a target="page2.html" in the home.html